# Unable to bind values to input box on Jsp page in angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jsp

I used angular in my jsp page but I'm confused how to bind values to inputbox

Here My is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCustomerPage(Model model,HttpSession session){
```

CustomerBean customerBean = getCustomerById(id);
    model.addAttribute("customer", customerBean);
    return "addCustomer"
    }

My jsp code

```
<input type="text" name="customerName" value="${customer.name}" ng-model="cust.name" required/>
```

Unable to bind value

But if i removed ng-model then value bind to control
i.e

```
<input type="text"  name="customerName" value="${customer.name}" required/>
```

this works

Help!

Comment: if you are using JSP page then what is the use of using angularjs. AngularJs use for light web page, if you are using angularjs then use html file instead of using jsp file.

Comment: ng-value="${customer.name}"  not working :(